# Specify which version of strip to use during rpm build process

Tags: rpmbuild, binutils

I have installed an updated gcc compiler suite and binutils on my RHEL6 system. These installations do not interfere with the system versions. However, when I build a static library with rpmbuild (using my upgraded compiler), I get errors when rpmbuild executes `strip`. It uses the system version, installed in `/usr/bin/strip`, rather than my updated version. I have verified that if I run strip manually from my updated install, everything is fine. I can reproduce the error by using `/usr/bin/strip`.

Is there a way to make rpmbuild use my custom binutils rather than the system one?

Comment: You should really be using [SCL](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/)s which would solve this problem without any hackish stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
%define __strip /your/binutils/bin/strip
%define __objdump /your/binutils/bin/objdump
```

to the top of your spec file. I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate way to do this, but it works.

Comment: `%global` would only parse once. Otherwise, this is how you can do it.